# High $R^2$ on Ordinary least squares model with violated assumptions. Is it good?

Tags: regression, least-squares

Recently I tried to fit some points which (from the plot) seems linearly distributed. 
The fit result (in R) is:

```
Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-112223   -2532    2021    3698   83241 

Coefficients:
              Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) -6.623e+03  7.136e+02  -9.282   <2e-16 ***
population   5.946e-02  4.278e-04 138.986   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 12780 on 379 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.9808,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.9807 
F-statistic: 1.932e+04 on 1 and 379 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

With $R^2$ 0.98. Nice! BUT I checked the OLS assumptions and from the graph I have heteroscedasticity (top-left and bottom-left graph) and I have no normality of errors (top-right graph).

[image]

So I transformed the dependent and independent variables with log transformation. I now have a model which meet all the assumptions but it is more complicated (exponential fit?) and with lower $R^2$: 0.96.

```
Residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-0.37058 -0.06061 -0.00701  0.05532  0.44428 

Coefficients:
               Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)    -2.08467    0.06153  -33.88   <2e-16 ***
log_population  1.12146    0.01120  100.12   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.101 on 379 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.9636,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.9635 
F-statistic: 1.002e+04 on 1 and 379 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

Which is the best? Is the first model wrong, and why?

Comment: What do you mean by best? Causal effects? Prediction? Fit? The $R^2$ is very poor indication of any of these "bests"...

Comment: See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/13314/is-r2-useful-or-dangerous

Comment: What kind of data is that? By any chance, are you regressing one random walk on another?

Comment: What happens to $R^2$ when you remove observation 249 from the dataset and refit the models?

Comment: @Repmat Causal effect (?) and fit...

Comment: @RichardHardy it's about GDP and population of some cities.

Comment: @whuber I tried removing observation 249 and 381 (which is kinda outlier when I remove 249) and I have r-squared 0.972

Comment: OK, that may very well be the case of fitting one random walk against another which is not permitted under OLS assumptions. You may refer to spurious regression and perhaps cointegration.